# Is their a way to protect screens from being recorded?

Tags: visible-light, refraction, frequency, wavelength, vision

[image]

This idea might sound stupid but...
Is there a way a screen would be impossible to record using a prism? I’m not talking recorded by a software but recorded from a camera…

If you put a prism layer in front on a screen, the screen would not be able to be recorded. The color spectrum would then be dispersed. If someone looks at this dispersed color spectrum using prism glasses, could the glasses recombine the initial image the screen is projecting? It would work a bit like the double prism experiment…

I know my sketch probably makes to sense and it would be way more complicated than what the picture represents, but could this idea possibly work one way or another?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If your eye can read the screen, a camera can read it.  Your eye is essentially a camera.

Comment: So in other words, there's no way a screen could be watched by users but completely protected from being recorded?

Comment: It's always risky to say something's impossible.  If the problem to be solved is to prevent cameras from "looking over your shoulder", then there may be effective solutions.  A screen that projects its image directly toward the user's eye and nowhere else can be made and would solve the problem.  But in that case "smart eyeglasses" or AR eyewear might solve the problem equally well.

Answer (score 0):

This approach can obfuscate the screen for a human and make the screen difficult to interpret but a camera would still be able to record the different colors arriving at different locations on its sensor, which is somewhat-equivalent to recording a blurred image. The blurred image could easily be deblurred digitally if the properties of the first prism are known.